# Debug Javascript in Android WebView from same app

Tags: javascript, android, debugging

I'm experimenting with a simple `Javascript` debugger for a `WebView`. I'd like to debug/control/inspect how some `Javascript` code is being executed inside my `WebView`.

I haven't found any solution other than using the `WebChromeClient` to receive the console messages.

Since I have access to the `Javascript` code I can add instrumentation code: a `console.log` call before each line, with a special message (e.g. `"debugging line 3"`) that tells which lines have been executed.

It's quite rudimentary so I wonder if there's any better solution. It would be great if I could use the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement to really control execution flow.

Comment: Are you trying to debug on the mobile itself or on a desktop machine connected via USB to the mobile? Do you plan developing a debugging API or just use the existing Chrome toolset for debugging?

Comment: I'm trying to debug from the very android app that creates the web view. I haven't thought about a complete debugging api but something simpler (but sort of). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been doing if I want to console.log() anything directly on the mobile browser so that debugging can be done on the actual device and not in emulator or similar...

I made JS debugger plugin and here is what it have:

- it creates an absolutely positioned HTML element that is placed on top of the content and is semi transparent.
- I made the JS logic that actually simulates what console.log() does and print out all desired information in mentioned HTML element
- once plugin was done I simply used `MoibileDebugger.log('what ever');` instead of `console.log('what ever');`

My code is still not published publicly but will do that soon, so that anyone can benefit from using it...
In any case this plugin can be made very quickly by anyone who is good in JS.

Comment: So you're using a Javascript interface? I'd like to see what you're doing exactly. Thanks.